# How to get rid of null value exception

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to sum up all values in the cells of the rows and write the aggregated value in the bottom of the  table. 
I use this code

```
double Sum[] = new double[sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum()];
for (int i = 1; i < LastCellNum; i++)
{
    Sum[i - 1] = 0;

    for (int j = 1; j <= LastRowNum; j++)
    {
        cell = sheet.getRow(j).getCell(i);
        if (cell != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Sum[i - 1] = Sum[i - 1] + cell.getNumericCellValue();
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException ex)
            {
                //Handle NumberFormat and NullPointer exceptions here
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Handle generic exception here}
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Sum[i - 1]);
```

The code works properly and it could even print the Value of Sum, but after that I have `java.lang.NullPointerException`.
All the selected Cells in my file are either empty or contain numbers.

Comment: And unrelated: read about java naming conventions: variable names go camelCase. "Sum" is pretty misleading therefore. And hint: you dont **catch** and handle NPEs. They are BUGS. You fix them.

Comment: Please provide information about the line the exception is in. You can use `ex.printStacktrace()` to get a full stack trace.

Comment: `j <= LastRowNum`